# Saving threads in a Smalltalk VM image

Tags: smalltalk, gnu-smalltalk

I run the following GNU Smalltalk script:

```
stdout << 'Before'; nl.
ObjectMemory snapshot: 'image.im'.
stdout << 'After'; nl.
```

It produces this output, as expected, and writes out a new image:

```
Before
After
```

Now I reload the image:

```
$ gst -I image.im
```

What I would *expect* to see happen is that the word `After` gets printed --- execution resumes from the point where the image was saved in the original script. What *actually* happens is that I just get a REPL.

Obviously the image is either not saving the state of the thread which is running the script, or else the thread is not being recreated when the image gets loaded. I thought Smalltalk images were supposed to contain a snapshot of the entire state of the system; so why is this happening? (And is there any way I can make this work? I want to use this behaviour.)

Answer (score 1):

When stopping and restarting a smalltalk image, you run into the boundaries of how far the illusion of everything is an object can be maintained. Reopening a database connection, sockets, files, etc. is not guaranteed to be possible. The image might be reopened on another machine, in another network and years later. Different smalltalks make slightly different choices in how to deal with these issues. When running Seaside on Pharo, the server connection listening to new connections is restarted, the Seaside sessions themselves are flushed.

Comment: Well, yes, but threads are different --- Smalltalk threads are green thread implementations and are implemented entirely in the VM. You _can_ save a thread in the image and restore it (I've tried). I want to know why the thread which handles the script isn't being saved.

Comment: Is it possible that the thread exists but can't be connected to stdout? Perhaps the REPL already owns that socket.

Comment: The problem is not the thread. ObjectMemory and stdout both cannot maintain the object illusion perfectly.